# c# pagination show initial 10 then 5 at the time when clicking load more

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following paging logic that works very well. If I decide to load 5 items at the time (each time) it works fine. However I have the following scenario: I want to initially load 10 items and then each time user clicks load more I want to load 5 items. How can I do that?

```
public class Page
{
    public Page(int totalItems, int? page, int pageSize = 5)
    {
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)pageSize);
        var currentPage = page != null ? (int)page : 1;
        var startPage = currentPage - 5;
        var endPage = currentPage + 4;
        if (startPage <= 0)
        {
            endPage -= (startPage - 1);
            startPage = 1;
        }
        if (endPage > totalPages)
        {
            endPage = totalPages;
            if (endPage > 10)
            {
                startPage = endPage - 9;
            }
        }

        TotalItems = totalItems;
        CurrentPage = currentPage;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
        StartPage = startPage;
        EndPage = endPage;

        StartIndex = (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize;
        EndIndex = Math.Min(StartIndex + PageSize - 1, TotalItems - 1);
    }

    public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
    public int StartPage { get; private set; }
    public int EndPage { get; private set; }
    public int StartIndex { get; set; }
    public int EndIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of this class?

Comment: Code full of magic numbers...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if page is zero or 1 depending on the index you started if so this means that it is the first time and return 10 not five, then continue returning 5 as usual since page will be increased and the condition will not apply anymore